# complexity of set() function algorithm and the "&" operator when using together

Tags: python, algorithm, big-o, code-complexity

I want to calculate the big-o of this line of a code (that's for finding common elements in two arrays) of a given size n but I don't know how set works in Python. Also the "&" operator between them. Can someone help me to understand what exactly they do?

```
result = set(arr1) & set(arr2)
```

Comment: See https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Answer (score 1):

Given two sets `s1` and `s2`, on average the `&` operator is `O(min(len(s1), len(s2))`

The `&` operator calculates the intersection between two sets. This means that the resultant set will have only elements from both `s1` and `s2`.

For example:

```
{1, 2, 3, 4} & {3, 4, 5}
```

Output:

```
{3, 4}
```

The operation is roughly equal to:

```
def intersection(s1, s2):

    # make s1 the smaller set no matter what
    if len(s1) > len(s2): s1, s2 = s2, s1

    res = set()

    # iterate over all items in the smaller set and add if they are common to both sets
    for item in s1:
        if item in s2: res.add(item)
    return res
```

This time complexity is derived from the following. To build the resultant set, one has to iterate over each element in one of the sets and check if that element is inside the other set.

Iterating over all elements in one set is `O(N)`, while the `in` operation is on average `O(1)`, resulting in an overall `O(N)` runtime.

Since the set you iterate over doesn't actually matter, python saves some time by iterating over the smaller set to make the `N` in `O(N)` as small as possible, resulting in the `O(min(len(s1), len(s2))` complexity.

Do note that this is only the average case complexity. The worst (but super rare) case complexity for the `in` operation is `O(N)` if every single element in the set somehow has the same hash. This would give the `&` operation a worst case scenario of `O(len(s1) * len(s2))` complexity

Comment: Note, in this particular case, you iterate over both lists at least once to create the sets.